# MapBox: Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Im using MapBox in one of my web aplicatins, nad my goal is to render a basic map on the page.

I have the following script:

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = mapToken;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });
</script>
```

and to display the map, I use:

```
<div id='map' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div>
```

The problem is, when I try to load the page, nothing happens and I get the following error:
***Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined***

Comment: not the easiest thing to find, but you should refer to their [quick start guides](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#quickstart) - it will get you started with a basic map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem just by including this:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

in the head of the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

2022 Update

This was what worked for me

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you add this to your `block` `head` of your pug file if you're doing templating with `pug` library.

```
script(src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js')
link(href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet')
```